# Java Read song title

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

So i was confused and can really use some help
i have a code which gets all the mp3 and wav files from the sdcard and places them in a Arraylist hashmap. i am getting confused on trying to rather getting the title which is labelled in the sdcard but the actual song name. if someone can also help me with how to sort the hashmap into alphabetical order that would be great.

```
package com.androidhive.musicplayer;

import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SongsManager {
    final String MEDIA_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/";
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    private String mp3Pattern = ".mp3";
    private String wavPattern = ".wav";
    private String flacPattern = ".flac";

    // Constructor
    public SongsManager(){

    }

    /**
     * Function to read all mp3 files and store the details in
     * ArrayList
     * */
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // return songs list array
        return songsList;
    }

    private void scanDirectory(File directory) {
        if (directory != null) {
            File[] listFiles = directory.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addSongToList(File song) {
        if ((song.getName().endsWith(mp3Pattern)) || song.getName().endsWith(wavPattern) || song.getName().endsWith(flacPattern)) {
            HashMap<String, String> songMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            songMap.put("songTitle",
                    song.getName().substring(0, (song.getName().length() - 4)));
            songMap.put("songPath", song.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(songMap);
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: "sort the hashmap into alphabetical order" this phrasing makes no sense. By definition, a HashMap does not guarantee any ordering of its elements.

Comment: @Kon is correct on that front.  If you want sorting, use `TreeMap`. :)

Comment: @Jeff.. Correct me if am wrong. He creates one HashMap for each song to include title and path. Which means, that HashMap now would have only one song detail. If you listen closer, he doesn't put all songs in same HashMap, but one HashMap per song and adds each HashMap into list. so we can't suggest him to use TreeMap. Rather, the list has to be sorted based on HashMap Object using comparator or so. am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Implementing `Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>` would solve your issue.

Create a class that implements Comparator interface that compares HashMaps based on any specific key (your case would be songTitle). I kept that comparator class below.

```
class MapComparator implements Comparator<HashMap<String, String>>{

    private String key;

    public MapComparator(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(HashMap<String, String> o1, HashMap<String, String> o2) {
        String val1 = o1.get(key);
        String val2 = o2.get(key);
        return val1.compareTo(val2);
    }

}
```

Now all you have to do is, sort your list before it is returned.

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList() {
        System.out.println(MEDIA_PATH);
        if (MEDIA_PATH != null) {
            File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
            File[] listFiles = home.listFiles();
            if (listFiles != null && listFiles.length > 0) {
                for (File file : listFiles) {
                    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        scanDirectory(file);
                    } else {
                        addSongToList(file);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // Sort your list before returning
        Collections.sort(songsList, new MapComparator("songTitle"));
        return songsList;
    }
```

Now you will get songs in sorted order based on songTitle. Hope it solves your issue.

Comment: Am not sure why it's been given down vote. Can someone explain so I can correct it? Btw, I have tried the same before I answered and seen it worked & I got sorted list based on any specified key in HashMap. I edited my answer with the code I used.